# How to read dBm from a AD8318 RF power detector chip?

Tags: rf

I am trying to measure RF power of my 2.4g Wi-Fi stick using AD8318 evaluation board. If using 40dB attenuator, I am measuring 0.8 minimum volts at the output of AD8318 on my oscilloscope.

So looking at the graph on page 8 of AD8318 datasheet, it says around -13dBm. So 40-13=27dBm.

Am I right that my 2.4G Wi-Fi stick is outputting 27dBm RF power? Please guide. Thanks.

[Link to the datasheet:](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8318.pdf)

Comment: Exactly which AD8318 evaluation board are you using? What does '0.8 **minimum** volts' mean? There are 6 graphs on page 8. Which one are you looking at?

Comment: I am using "https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/AD8318-EVALZ/1166810" . By 0.8min V I meant that the output voltage of AD8318 drops to 0.8V while measuring the RF burst waveform.I am looking at the fig6 graph.

Comment: The maximum output power of a WiFi device should be limited to 100 mW which is +20 dBm. Assuming that the AD8318 is measuring that power properly than indeed your device outputs +27 dBm which is a bit high.

Comment: Its Ubiquiti Wifi Station EXT which is rated at +30dBm (1W).

Comment: At 20 cm away from your WiFi stick you should measure -40 dBm or something like that.